# How to get minx, miny, maxx and maxy of a geometry?

Tags: oracle-spatial

I'm new to Oracle Spatial.
In MySQL or PostGIS, it's easy to get minx miny maxx maxy of a geometry, any and/or all of them. But how to do that in Oracle Spatial?

Do I need to chain up several functions and properties to get any of them? Well this doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various functions you can use to get the minimum bounding rectangle in Oracle Spatial:

- SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR
- SDO_MIN_MBR_ORDINATE
- SDO_MAX_MBR_ORDINATE

There are lots of examples here:

http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/55/oracle-locator-vs-enterprise-licensing-the-sdogeom-package

in section 2, which hopefully will help.  It depends a bit what you're trying to get as to which one you would use.  I generally end up using SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR most of the time but you do usually end up with a few functions chained together as you say.

Comment: Thanks! However, it's a bit frustrated to hear that chaining up is the only solution.